# How to access the value of the chosen input radio option with angular

Tags: angular

My question is pretty much formulated in the topic already.

But to describe the problem more: Lets say I have a form with three radio buttons. each one has another value obviously. Now I want to use the value in my component, according to the choosing of the user.

I think the solution might be pretty easy, but I couldn't find anything, that is working properly and is up to date.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you may share some code you have tried and that didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you use `<mat-radio-group>` and `<mat-radio-button>`

In this case I'll recommend to use a `(change)` event and use `$event.value`

in your html

```
<mat-radio-group >
  <mat-radio-button (change)="getValue($event.value)" value="1">1</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button (change)="getValue($event.value)" value="2">2</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

in your ts

```
currentValue:string;

getValue(value:string){
  this.currentValue = value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
  <label *ngFor="let radiobutton of radioItems">
    <input type="radio" name="options" (change)="getValue(radiobutton.value)" value="radiobutton.value"> 
    {{radiobutton}}
  </label>
```

ts:

```
getValue(value) {
  //here you can get value
}
```

`radiobutton.value` this is value of your radio button